# Fastest method of filling a List(Of DataRow): SQLiteDataAdapter or SQLiteDataReader?

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I had always seen comments that a SQLiteDataReader is faster than a SQLiteDataAdapter, so I tried the following comparison on a table of 355,020 rows.

Test 1:

```
    Dim DRows As New List(Of DataRow)
    Try
        Connect() ' This creates and opens the connection
        Using tr As SQLiteTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction
            Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand
                cmd.Connection = conn
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `admin_class`;"
                Using da As New SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd)
                    Dim dt As New DataTable
                    da.Fill(dt)
                    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                        For a As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                            DRows.Add(dt.Rows(a))
                        Next
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using
            tr.Commit()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
```

Test 2:

```
    Dim DRows As New List(Of DataRow)
    Try
        Connect() ' This creates and opens the connection
        Using tr As SQLiteTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction
            Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand
                cmd.Connection = conn
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `admin_class`;"
                Dim dr As SQLiteDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                Using dt As New DataTable
                    dt.Load(dr)
                    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                        For a As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                            DRows.Add(dt.Rows(a))
                        Next
                    End If
                End Using
                dr.Close()
            End Using
            tr.Commit()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
```

Surprisingly, the first code took 2.361 seconds, and the second code took 4.970 seconds. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it would make a difference but there's no point using a `Using` block for the `DataTable` in the second code snippet - you're not in the first - but you should for the data reader. You should time the `Fill` and `Load` calls specifically as they are the real difference.

Comment: I would ask why you want a `List(Of DataRow)` anyway. It seems an odd thing to want `DataRow` objects while discarding the `DataTable` they belong to.

Comment: `SQLiteTransaction`? Nothing here to commit to the DB nor to RollBack. If you really need to return a `List(Of DataRow)` then in both examples replace the loops with `DRows.AddRange(dt.Rows.OfType(Of DataRow))` or `DRows = New List(Of DataRow)(dt.Rows.OfType(Of DataRow))` and try.

Comment: @user18387401 - The idea was to have a a general purpose SQLite access routine that could be called throughout my program. I did try outputting the DataTable instead of the List(Of DataRows), but that proved to be hugely slower. However, I did use a Reader rather than an Adaptor,in the code so that might be part of the problem too. I must narrow down exactly what is going on.

Comment: *"I did try outputting the DataTable instead of the List(Of DataRows), but that proved to be hugely slower"*. How is that possible, given that you can't get the `DataRows` to put in the `List` without having a `DataTable` first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment on SQLite directly but I just executed this code:

```vb
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Module Program

    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim timer = Stopwatch.StartNew()

        Dim table As New DataTable

        Using connection As New SqlConnection("connection string here"),
              command As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM MyTable", connection)
            connection.Open()

            Using reader = command.ExecuteReader()
                table.Load(reader)
            End Using
        End Using

        timer.Stop()

        Console.WriteLine(timer.Elapsed)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

in a .NET 6 Console app three times against a table with just over 1.5 million records and got the following output:

> 00:00:07.1881430
>
> 00:00:07.2306110
>
> 00:00:07.1166125

I then switched to this code:

```vb
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Module Program

    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim timer = Stopwatch.StartNew()

        Dim table As New DataTable

        Using connection As New SqlConnection("connection string here"),
              adapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MyTable", connection)
            adapter.Fill(table)
        End Using

        timer.Stop()

        Console.WriteLine(timer.Elapsed)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

and got this output:

> 00:00:03.5211019
>
> 00:00:03.4162924
>
> 00:00:03.4639760

That tells me that you're not doing anything wrong and the data adapter is just faster than the data reader when populating a `DataTable`. I'm guessing that it's because there's some doubling up of work with the data reader, where the data adapter knows the data is going directly to the `DataTable`, but I don't know for sure. I will do a bit of investigation and see if I can pinpoint the reason and post back if I find something.

Comment: You missed the `DRows.Add(...` part in your test Johni. That counts.

Comment: @dr.null, it actually doesn't count. Copying rows from a `DataTable` to a `List(Of DataRow)` would not be affected at all by how the `DataTable` was populated. It wouldn't even be affected by the number of columns in the table; only by the number of rows, because it's just copying a reference for each one. The generation/populating of the list will take the same amount of time in each case. The difference is in the population of the `DataTable`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my results using 8 different methods (only code that differs is shown):

Method 1 - Fills the 'DRows' list, using a SQLiteDataAdapter

```
    Using da As New SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For a As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                DRows.Add(dt.Rows(a))
            Next
        End If
    End Using
```

Method 2 - Returns a DataTable, using an SQLiteDataAdapter

```
    Using da As New SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(dt)
    End Using
```

Method 3 - Fills the 'DRows' list, using a SQLiteDataReader

```
    Using dr As SQLiteDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        Using dt As New DataTable
            dt.Load(dr)
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                For a As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                    DRows.Add(dt.Rows(a))
                Next
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
```

Method 4 - Returns a DataTable, using a DataReader

```
    Using dr As SQLiteDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        dt.Load(dr)
    End Using
```

Method 5 - Fills the 'DRows' list, using a SQLiteDataAdapter, and AddRange

```
    Using da As New SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd)
         Dim dt As New DataTable
         da.Fill(dt)
         DRows.AddRange(dt.Rows.OfType(Of DataRow))
    End Using
```

Method 6 - Fills the 'DRows' list, using a SQLiteDataAdapter, and New List

```
    Using da As New SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)
        DRows = New List(Of DataRow)(dt.Rows.OfType(Of DataRow))
    End Using
```

Method 7 - Fills the 'DRows' list, using a SQLiteDataReader, and AddRange

```
    Using dr As SQLiteDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        Using dt As New DataTable
            dt.Load(dr)
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                DRows.AddRange(dt.Rows.OfType(Of DataRow))
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
```

Method 8 - Fills the 'DRows' list, using a SQLiteDataReader, and New List

```
    Using dr As SQLiteDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        Using dt As New DataTable
            dt.Load(dr)
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                DRows = New List(Of DataRow)(dt.Rows.OfType(Of DataRow))
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
```

Results sorted by time:

```
    RunTime: 04.415 for Method 5(DataAdaptor, fills DRows, with AddRange)
    RunTime: 04.573 for Method 2(DataAdaptor, returns DataTable)
    RunTime: 04.667 for Method 5(DataAdaptor, fills DRows, with AddRange)
    RunTime: 04.678 for Method 6(DataAdaptor, fills DRows, with New List)
    RunTime: 04.681 for Method 1(DataAdaptor, fills DRows, with Loop)
    RunTime: 04.687 for Method 2(DataAdaptor, returns DataTable)
    RunTime: 04.712 for Method 2(DataAdaptor, returns DataTable)
    RunTime: 04.720 for Method 6(DataAdaptor, fills DRows, with New List)
    RunTime: 04.740 for Method 1(DataAdaptor, fills DRows, with Loop)
    RunTime: 04.861 for Method 1(DataAdaptor, fills DRows, with Loop)
    RunTime: 04.884 for Method 6(DataAdaptor, fills DRows, with New List)
    RunTime: 04.932 for Method 5(DataAdaptor, fills DRows, with AddRange)
    RunTime: 06.479 for Method 3(DataReader, fills DRows, with Loop)
    RunTime: 06.559 for Method 3(DataReader, fills DRows, with Loop)
    RunTime: 06.694 for Method 4(DataReader, returns DataTable)
    RunTime: 06.710 for Method 7(DataReader, fills DRows, with AddRange)
    RunTime: 06.730 for Method 8(DataReader, fills DRows, with New List)
    RunTime: 06.801 for Method 8(DataReader, fills DRows, with New List)
    RunTime: 06.805 for Method 8(DataReader, fills DRows, with New List)
    RunTime: 06.835 for Method 7(DataReader, fills DRows, with AddRange)
    RunTime: 06.887 for Method 3(DataReader, fills DRows, with Loop)
    RunTime: 06.887 for Method 4(DataReader, returns DataTable)
    RunTime: 06.887 for Method 4(DataReader, returns DataTable)
    RunTime: 06.965 for Method 7(DataReader, fills DRows, with AddRange)
```

Comment: Yes, `.AddRange` works faster and better than `.Add` as per their doc remarks sections. The source code of the methods tell us more. Use `SQLiteDataReader` if you don't need to return a `DataTable` and you need to return a `List<T>` where `T` is a model that holds some or all of the readers fields. Otherwise `SQLiteDataAdapter`, just fill and return.

Comment: What surprises me is that the DataAdapter is consistently faster than the DataReader, despite many sites claiming the opposite. It really pays to make a test-project to compare methods before committing it to the main solution.

Comment: The data reader is a Forward-Only-Read-Only mechanism, it can be the right tool in many tasks and scenarios. Your example is not included. We need to understand these tools to decide when and where to use them. The example in my first comment is one.